# .file() method not working while implementing Duck Typing in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, ecmascript-6, duck-typing

I am trying to implement duck typing in java-script for first time to avoid lengthy conditional statements. Below is my duck typing code

```
// A simple array where we keep track of things that are filed.
filed = [];

function fileIt(thing) {
// Dynamically call the file method of whatever
// `thing` was passed in.
thing.file();

// Mark as filed
filed.push(thing);
}

function AuditForm(reportType) {
this.reportType = reportType;
}

AuditForm.prototype.file = function () {
console.log("Hello from Here!!!");
//Call Ajax here and then populate grid
}

 var AuditForm = new AuditForm("AuditForm");
```

and here is how i am calling it

```
 fileIt("AuditForm");
```

with above code, i am able to hit to **fileIt(thing)** function but getting unknown error at `thing.file();`
What's wrong here..Kindly suggest.

Comment: You're passing the function a string, should it not be `fileIt(AuditForm);`

Comment: @George Thanks, Now, i am trying to pass  `formID` from `var formID = obj.id;`still getting error.What's wrong in this one? `formID` has value of `auditform`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var auditForm = new AuditForm("AuditForm");
fileIt(auditForm);
```

You were passing a string to `fileIt` instead of something that has the `file()` function.

Comment: Thanks, Now, i am trying to pass  `formID` from `var formID = obj.id;`still getting error.What's wrong in this one? `formID` has value of `auditform`

Comment: Open a different question including debugging output of console.log(obj.id) at least.